# Cross-site publishing on SharePoint 2013 Standard

Tags: sharepoint-server, cross-site-publishing

I'm trying to set up cross-site publishing on the SharePoint 2013 Standard version, on premise. While trying to activate cross-site collection publishing feature I get the error as [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/51ae9401-8227-44d2-9fb7-c2ce8b54adce/error-activating-cross-site-collection-publishing-feature-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment) 
**NOSCOPE**
The feature you are trying to activate is dependent on another feature 592ccb4a-9304-49ab-aab1-66638198bb58 contained in the solution 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 which is not installed.

The essense of this problem resultion in the post I mentioned is that you need to get Enterprise version of Sharepoint 2013. This seems to be confirmed in [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635883%28v=office.15%29.aspx) technet article as it applies to Enterprise edition.

However, [here](http://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-hosting/2013/compare-sharepoint-server-standard-enterprise/) I get that cross-site publishing should available on Standard edition.
Can somebody confirm/deny the availability of the cross-site publishing feature on the Standard edition of Sharepoint 2013? If it is available how do you resolve the **NO SCOPE** error?
Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be available in Standard edition.
At least a couple articles showing that it's available only on Enterprise:

http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/01/14/sharepoint-2013-feature-comparison-chart-all-editions/

Technet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635883(v=office.15).aspx

Here's a link for someone that got the same error:
http://www.mindsharp.com/blog/2013/03/sharepoint-2013-managed-navigation-error/

And a list of the features for SP2013 in its different versions. http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2013/10/sharepoint-enterprise-feature-activation-unintended-consequences/

Hope this might help.