# Why does Cross-Site Collection Publishing feature appear in SharePoint 2013 standard?

Tags: 2013, cross-site-publishing

If I understand [Microsoft's licensing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj819267.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) correctly, Cross Site Collection Publishing is only available for the Enterprise on-premises version of SharePoint 2013.  When we attempt to activate it, we get the same error as [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94517/cross-site-publishing-on-sharepoint-2013-standard).  I'm just curious as to why this feature shows as "activate-able" in my Site Collection Features when it's clearly not something we can use?

Comment: haha..maybe just to let you know that feature is there in enterprise so buy it :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can think, Cross-Site Publishing Features itself is standard but it requires a couple of dependent features( one of them showed the error is SearchDrivenContent feature) are Enterprise edition.

Also, this is part of the publishing site and automatically showed in the site collection features list. Maybe Microsoft thinks it is good to show people the features name so that they think about it.

Maybe they forget to mark it hidden in the Standard features.